# Can you see the evaluation stack in mdbg?

Tags: .net, cil, ilasm, mdbg

Say I have the following CIL:

```
ldc.i4 40 <- a breakpoint is set here
ldc.i4.2
add
box int32
call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

I then use `ilasm /debug main.il` to assemble the exe and pdb files to use in mdbg.

---

My question is, when I'm at say line 3, before the `add` operation is executed, I would want to see the **evaluation stack** which would show me the two int32 constants, 40 and 2, which I had loaded before.

How can I view this evaluation stack in mdbg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the command that's needed to view the evaluation stack while debugging in mdbg:  `p[rint]`.

```
p[rint]       prints local or debug variables
```